# Enable touches in scrollview

Tags: ios4

First I am setting color to the background and then I am adding my image to the scrollview. Now I can able to zoom the image and then scroll. But my problem is, i want to erase the image by moving the cursor. so that my background color can be visible. Here, I am writing the code to erase the image in touch move. But the touches on scrollview is not working.

Is there any alternate method to erase my image by moving the cursor. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day.....